# Class with Multidimensional Container

Tags: c++, qt, vector, multidimensional-array, containers

I am working on a Recurrent Neural Network in C++ using the Qt library. It gets constructed with a vector containing the topology where the number of elements define the number of layers and each element specifies the number of neurons in each layer.

The problem at hand is that the class needs to store some weights in matrices which depend on the size of the elements as well as their number is depended on the size of the vector. Required is a fast and efficient, index based access, 3 dimensional (of which one dimension differs in size) container. It does not necessarily be able to be resizable but AFAIK it can not be preallocated bevor the constructor, since size and number is given with the constructor.

1. I tried to store them in a nested vector but except from problems how to work with that I already read that nested vectors do not have a good performance, e.g.

   typedef QVector < QVector < QVector < double> > > Weights;
2. I read something about ‘Dynamically Allocated Multi-Dimensional Arrays’ using arrays of pointer pointing to arrays of pointers pointing to ... and so on. This did not look very elegant.
3. Qt also provides some Matrix classes but since I can not preallocate them I neglected those.
4. Taking some additional library like [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).
5. Another solution might be writing some class or custom container for my needs but I would rather not unless this is really the best way to do it.

So I am asking for advise what is the way to go here? Is there even a possibility to preallocate the memory or does it need to be dynamic?

Disclaimer: I am aware that there are a lot of similar questions around but they seem to lack comparing possibilities also I am not always sure if the underlying situation is the same.

Comment: If by "preallocate" you mean "store on stack", then it's generally a bad idea(tm) anyway.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean by nested vectors having bad performance. You could also flatten that out for sure, but I am not sure it is worth it, really.

Comment: @friendzis, with preallocating I mean defining the size of the container e.g. int[10][2].

Comment: @TheMindWithin: yes, that is kind of bad idea, but still: I have not seen your benchmark about using the reserve method of std::vector or QVector.

Comment: @LaszloPapp, dunno I just read that the memory allocation of the nested vectors is not next to each other, but I liked your proposal for QList<QVector2D> this in fact might be a solution.

Comment: @TheMindWithin: that is a bad idea... QVector2D is not QVector<QVector<...>>, but a vector for x and y, like in eigen with 2 dimensions.

Comment: @LaszloPapp, Yes I figured that for this one space has to be predefined as well. Currently this is my [solution](http://pastebin.com/aVuRnRsn). But still, there might be a better way...